# Que signifie "apoloche" ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Bonjour,

Dans *Le pont de Londres* :

> Non c'est pas ça... c'est du Yard! Les autres ils sont venus nous
> renifler... c'est du pigeon et compagnie!... T'as pas compris
> l'apoloche?

Savez-vous ce que signifie *apoloche* ici ?  J'ai trouvé dans ce [site](https://www.mollat.com/livres/60174/robert-gordienne-dictionnaire-argotique-des-trucs-des-bidules-et-des-machins#) la définition suivante :

> Apoloche n.f. · Désigne, en passant par la Lorraine, une histoire
> invraisemblable. Syn. Coquecigrue. NB À ne pas confondre avec
> l'apologie de Socrate.

Pensez-vous qu'il s'agit d'une définition adéquate au sens exprimé par la citation ci-dessus ?

Answer (score 3):

D'après [cette page](https://duclos.tripod.com/Dictiona.htm), il s'agit d'un néologisme de Céline, dérivé d'[apologue](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apologue) :

> APOLOCHE n.f.
> Néologisme, déformation d'*apologue*. Le glossaire de la Pléiade indique que le mot apparaît plus souvent chez Céline sous la forme *poloche*. Histoire, et par glissement de sens, affaire.
> 'Mais tout le monde connaît l'apoloche, c'était à qui le ferait grimper' Pléiade IV, App. II, 645.
> 'T'as pas compris l'apoloche ?' GBII, 641.